# What's a good Lightroom Alternative that sorts images by dimensions and aspect ratios?

Tags: lightroom, file-management

I'm a freelancer that just got a job editing images for video games that will later be used to post on the Xbox, PlayStation and Nintendo Marketplaces.

I'm trying to maximize my efficiency, and one thing that's taking a considerable amount of time is sorting through all the images and finding the images that fit the aspect ratio or resolution required by the platform.

I'm given maybe 200 random images of all different sizes and aspect ratios for one game to go through and put together the images needed for these platforms and it's almost a nightmare to try and manually sort through them as I couldn't find an option in Lightroom to sort by dimensions or aspect ratios (I do see Portrait and Landscape but I'm given a list of 1:1, 16:9, 2:3, 3:4, etc.)

Has anyone found, perhaps, an alternative to Lightroom that has these sorting or filtering capabilities?  Or perhaps some other work arounds?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with free software - [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/). In Browser mode you can select icon with folders on right, select Details and then click on the column you want to use for sort.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Bridge

In Adobe Bridge you can sort by dimensions when you view your photos as a list.

[image]

This seems to sort your images from tall portraits to wide landscape (e.g. horizontal panoramas).

#### Lightroom

In Lightroom you can sort by aspect ratio when in the Library module:

[image]

This seems to sort your images from tall portraits to wide landscape (e.g. horizontal panoramas).

You can also create [smart collections](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/photo-collections.html) for different widths, heights and combinations of those:

[image]

#### macOS Finder

In Finder you can add a dimensions column in list view and sort by it:

[image]

This seems to be a numerical sort on the dimension `3744 x 5615` and `5616 x 3744` are seen as being equal.